# Example of a finite group for which $\mathbb Q$ is not injective.

Tags: representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra, group-cohomology, injective-module

I had to prove that the cohomology with rational coefficients of any finite group is trivial. I tried to prove it by proving that $\mathbb Q$ is an injective $G$-module, however it doesn't seem to me to be the case.

Are there any easy to construct counter examples? Is it even true for any non trivial $G$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trivial representation $\mathbb{Q}$ is an injective $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module for any finite group $G$.  To prove this, suppose $N$ is a module with a submodule $M$ and $f:M\to \mathbb{Q}$ is a homomorphism; we wish to extend $f$ to a homomorphism $\tilde{f}:N\to \mathbb{Q}$.  First, since $\mathbb{Q}$ is an injective $\mathbb{Z}$-module, we can extend $f$ to a $\mathbb{Z}$-homomorphism $g:N\to\mathbb{Q}$.  Now the trick is that we can make $g$ become $G$-equivariant by averaging.  That is, define $$\tilde{f}(x)=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{a\in G}g(ax).$$  Then $\tilde{f}$ is $G$-equivariant (for any $b\in G$, $\tilde{f}(bx)$ is the same as $f(x)$ since the summands just get permuted), and extends $f$ since $f$ was $G$-equivariant so all the summands are the same when $x\in M$.

More generally, a similar argument shows that any $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module which is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space is injective (if $G$ acts nontrivially, you need to replace $g(ax)$ with $a^{-1}g(ax)$ in the sum above).